# Cannot sort documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database

I have a MongoDBcollection with documents like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52e24594ff4fdd1ce3d5f7aa"), "usr_id" : 86770651, "id" : NumberLong("426667781770055680"), "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52e247f3ff4fdd1ce3d5f8b8"), "usr_id" : 1374080503, "id" : NumberLong("426670940190023680"), "count" : 31 }
```

I want to sort this in descending order of count. I used this syntax

```
db.collection_name.aggregate ( $sort : {'count' : -1});
```

But it shows syntax error

```
 Sat Jan 25 11:31:22.626 SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Then I tried spacing out the syntax

```
db.collection_name.aggregate ( $ sort : { 'count' : -1 } ) ;
```

But now it shows

```
Sat Jan 25 11:33:18.415 SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I checked the various solutions to similar problems here on stackoverflow, and they say my answer is correct. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is wrap every pipeline operation in curly brackets :

`db.collection_name.aggregate ( {$sort : {'count' : -1}});`

The space doesn't matter

Also, you can sort without using aggregation:

`db.collection_name.find().sort({'count' : -1})`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Also, is there any reason I would not want to use aggregation?

Comment: For such a simple query like that where you dont need `$group`, `$project` , `$unwind` ..., you don't really need it